# Getting Tableau results in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tableau-api

I wanted to write a Python code that fetches results from Tableau(Like I can fetch AWS Redshift results in python using pyscopg2). Or is there any API that python can use to fetch my tableau results?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I only know about python and not tableau, but one thing I've learned is that things are pretty accessible with Python, here, take a look at [what tableau have to say about python integration](https://community.tableau.com/thread/236479)

Tableau seems to have made a beta [server/client](https://github.com/tableau/TabPy)

[Here is a client](https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python) to communicate with the Tableau Restful API